# Greenplum issue - HDFS Protocol Installation for GPHDFS access to HDP 2.x cluster

Tags: greenplum, hawq

When i am trying to read external table using GPHDFS Protocol. Additionally, I am not able to access HDP2.X files via greenplum cluster.

**Getting Error**

```
devdata=# select count(*) from schema.ext_table;
ERROR:  external table gphdfs protocol command ended with error. Error occurred during initialization of VM  (seg5 slice1 datanode0:40001 pid=13407)
DETAIL:  
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
Command: 'gphdfs://Authorithy/path
```

**More symptoms**

Not able to run Hadoop list file command  from gpadmin user at greenplum cluster.

that is

```
gpadmin$hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://namenode/file/path
```

**We tried :** 
checked Setting related to gphdfs vm paramteres.

Comment: Please provide the create external table command.  Your "OutOfMemoryError" is concerning too so provide the memory details of your GPDB cluster.

Comment: cannot create native thread means you need more virtual address space. what's overcommit value? overcommit ratio? swap space? gp_vmem_protect_limit?